# How to infer document layout aspect ratio using textract ocr?

Tags: python, ocr

I am stuck in a problem statement which requires to infer aspect ratio of the original document. As  I don't have access to Original Dcoument and its dimensions. The output of textract OCR is normalised. I have only some crucial information. Below is one such example of textract ocr.

```
{'Pages': [{'PageNumber': 1,
   'Width': 0.9985242,
   'Height': 1.0,
   'Regions': [{'Coordinates': {'Left': 0.02995922,
      'Top': 0.01522656,
      'Right': 0.1684075,
      'Bottom': 0.09595667,
      'CenterX': 0.09918336,
      'CenterY': 0.055591615},
     'Paragraphs': [{'Lines': [{'LineNumber': 1,
         'TextBlocks': [{'Words': [{'Text': 'Vishal',
             'Coordinates': {'Left': 0.02995922,
              'Top': 0.01522656,
              'Right': 0.1684075,
              'Bottom': 0.09595667,
              'CenterX': 0.09918336,
              'CenterY': 0.055591615}}]}]}],
       'ParagraphNumber': 1}],
     'RegionNumber': 1},
    {'Coordinates': {'Left': 0.1949253,
      'Top': 0.03882421,
      'Right': 0.4944748,
      'Bottom': 0.0720913,
      'CenterX': 0.34470005,
      'CenterY': 0.055457755},
     'Paragraphs': [{'Lines': [{'LineNumber': 2,
         'TextBlocks': [{'Words': [{'Text': 'Account Number',
             'Coordinates': {'Left': 0.1949253,
              'Top': 0.03882421,
              'Right': 0.4944748,
              'Bottom': 0.0720913,
              'CenterX': 0.34470005,
              'CenterY': 0.055457755}}]}]}],
       'ParagraphNumber': 2}],
```

Likewise there are millions of textract OCR outputs. How can I infer original layout using such details.

I have tried using getting the width and height of the largest text length inside the OCR, like

`Width = 0.35678/len(text). Height = 0.156889. Aspect Ratio = Width/Height.`